# Not able to install Homebrew on Apple M1 running Sonoma 14.2.1

Tags: git, homebrew, apple-m1, macos-sonoma

I want to install Git. According to https://git-scm.com/download/mac, Homebrew is prerequisite to install Git.
Desktop: Apple M1
macOS: Sonoma 14.2.1
Xcode version: 15.2 (Downloaded from apple developer website)

I am using the following bash command to install Homebrew:
`</bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)">`

```
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
```

```
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew
```

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R sanjeevjoshi:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...

```
xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need '')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need ''))).
Failed during: /usr/bin/git -c init.defaultBranch=master init --quiet
```

I can not decipher the output. On the Git website, it is mentioned that Apple ships a binary package of Git with Xcode. Does that have something to do with failed Homebrew installation? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-- Sanjeev

Comment: I have no idea why my output was curtailed. Here is the full output from the bash command I used to install Homebrew:

Comment: xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need '')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need ''))).
Failed during: /usr/bin/git -c init.defaultBranch=master init --quiet

Comment: Your help in decoding why Homebrew installation fails will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need Homebrew. Git is shipped with Xcode.

Comment: Hi Siguza, My system: Desktop: Apple M1 macOS: Sonoma 14.2.1 Xcode version: 15.2

Comment: Hi Siguza, When I type git -version, I get following output "xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need '')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need ''))). Any suggestions?

Comment: Siguza, I installed Xcode from the Apple developer site. God knows what went wrong. Then I reinstalled Xcode from the App store and at least got a legible output from the command, git --version -> git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145). Thank you.